# Visualforcepage

Tags: visualforce

Below is my visualforce page code :

```
<apex:page standardController="CDs__c" recordSetVar="CDs__c">
 <apex:pageBlock >
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CDs__c}" var="cash">
<apex:column value="{!cash.price__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!cash.quantity__c}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I want to see this VF page in my CDs object page layout. To display VF pages in a particular object's page layout we can use standard controller as that object and automatically VF option will be enabled in page layout. So in VF option (page layout) i am able to see all pages where i have used CDs as the standard controller but not the above page mentioned. I want the above page to be displayed in page layout ? How to do that ?

Comment: if you want to add some info to the question please use *edit* button, do not post additional info as comment and/or answer. To make sure your code is visible you have to put 4 whitespaces in front of it

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `recordSetVar="CDs__c"` page's attribute from your VF page to list it in VF page layout.

Comment: But if i do so, then VF page won't work.

Comment: But why to remove the attribute ?

Comment: I don't understand why you need list on standard page. Can you please list down the scenario what you are trying to do?

Comment: Your VF page deals with list of records due to recordSetVar, can be used to override "List" and can't be used in page layout. If you want to use it in page layout then you need to remove `recordSetVar="CDs__c"` and implement using another approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to display this onto a standard page. (I think that is what you are asking) then why not create this as a VF Component and the you can add it on the object layout.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more - I thought it was only a page that you could add to a layout - [Add Visualforce component to any page layout?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16779/add-visualforce-component-to-any-page-layout)

Comment: That is right, You will be using a page as a component. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/systems-integrator/2008/11/adding-a-visualforce-page-to-a-page-layout.html